# Dynamic html options using simple php 'crashes' server

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a dynamic html option field using the data filled in a php array. But my problem is the server 'crashes' when I open the page containing the code, meaning it is loading very slowly and not showing the whole page also the page freezes.
I'm wondering why this happens with such a simple code.

```
<?php
          if(isset($variants)){
            echo '<label for="exampleRecipientInput">Size</label>';
            echo '<select id="exampleRecipientInput">';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $variants; $i++) {
              echo '<option value="Option ',$i, ' ">',$variants[$i],'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
          }
?>
```

The data containing array gets created the following way

```
if (array_key_exists('Variants', $array[$productNumber])) {
      $variants = explode(",",$array[$productNumber]['Variants']);
}
```

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $variants; $i++)` since `$variants` is a array i think you need `count($variants)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $variants is an array, you have to use count() or, better way, use foreach.

In your current case, the loop never stops and that's why your server is crashing.

```
<?php
          if(isset($variants)){
            echo '<label for="exampleRecipientInput">Size</label>';
            echo '<select id="exampleRecipientInput">';
            foreach ($variants as $key => $val) {
              echo '<option value="Option ',$key, ' ">',$val,'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
          }
?>
```